# Prove for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^k}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Prove for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^k}=1$

**My attempt:**

Observe $k=1$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$. Let $x_n:=\sqrt[n]{n}-1$. Then:
$$n=(1+x_n)^n>1+\begin{pmatrix}n \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}x_n^2 \Longrightarrow n-1>\frac{n(n-2)}{2}x_n^2 \Longrightarrow x_n<\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$$

I am stuck proving it for every other $k$. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: **Hint:** $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$ and the function $x\mapsto e^x$ is continuous.

Comment: If you have it for $k=1$, then you're done, since $x_n \to x$ implies $x_n^k \to x^k$.

Comment: **Hint:** $\sqrt[n]{n^k}=\sqrt[n]n^k$

Comment: Ok, is my proof correct?